# assign "for loop" in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have this data frame t1

```
    id nobs
1   1  221
2   2  222
3   3  223
4   4  224
5   5  225
6   6  226
7   7  227
8   8  228
9   9  229
10 10  230
```

and I want to set a threshold for example of 225 to select only the id from 6-10. here is what I did I used a for loop:

```
> t2 <- for (i in 1:length(t1[,"nobs"]))
{
   a <- print({if(t1[, "nobs"][i] > threshold){TRUE}else{FALSE}})
}
```

it returns

```
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE

> t2
NULL
```

I don't understand here, I expect the same as the 10 logicals.

I want to assign the t2 to the logical vectors to t2. How can I do that? and why the numbers in [ ] are all 1 instead of 1 to 10. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

```
print(t1$nobs>225)
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

R is a vectorized language, meaning that nearly all functions (like `print(...)` for example) operate on vectors. You should (almost) never have to cycle through rows with a loop in R.

So `t1$nobs>225` is a vector with the same number of elements as there are rows in `t1` (10), and each element is the result of the logical comparison. `print(t1$nobs>225)` just prints the vector.

In response to OP's comment:

```
t2 <- t1$nobs>25
```

will create a vector `t2` of the same length as `t1` and set it to `TRUE` if `t1$nobs>225` and to `FALSE` otherwise.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. But I tried and the problem is still there. The result the exactly the same. I think it is the loop that creats the problem

Comment: I think we're missing each other here: *there is no loop*; just that one statement.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But could you please tell me why my t2 is NULL and it returns [1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE

Answer (score 0):

I'm not advocating this answer, but posting it to show how you can fix your existing code:

```
## Create an empty logical vector to hold your results
t2 <- logical(nrow(t1))

## This is what it looks like
t2
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

## Set your threshold
threshold <- 225

## Here's your new loop
for (i in 1:nrow(t1)) {
  t2[i] <- if (t1[, "nobs"][i] > threshold) TRUE else FALSE
}

## Now you need to return the output
t2
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Some notes about the loop:

- I assign the result directly to a given position in your "t2" vector.
- I don't use `print`, which just prints the output of each loop, but rather store the result in the vector.
- I drop a lot of your unnecessary brackets.

---

As @jlhoward has shown, however, there are much better ways to do this in R.